# How to associate a color with multiple images in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Photoshop - adjustment layer to change colors of multiple layers?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/photoshop-adjustment-layer-to-change-colors-of-multiple-layers)
>   [Is it possible to have global color swatches or color styles in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13787/is-it-possible-to-have-global-color-swatches-or-color-styles-in-photoshop)

I have a PSD filled with buttons and other controls. I want to theme those controls based on one color. Is there a way for me to associate one color with all the buttons and other controls in the PSD file such that I can change one color and the theme of all the buttons changes?

Thanks

Comment: This has little to do with photography. Illustrator has what you are thinking: pallets that link to objects. Photoshop your best bet is to have a solid layer applied with 'color' blending mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have global color swatches or color styles in Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13787/is-it-possible-to-have-global-color-swatches-or-color-styles-in-photoshop) and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/photoshop-adjustment-layer-to-change-colors-of-multiple-layers

Comment: I think you're question will be closed soon but the short answer you'll find in answers to the question Scott linked to: **Use Illustrator** ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are tying to get at.

But (based on what I think you're asking) I would use Groups ( *Layer > New > Group* ) and create a group for each theme.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the buttons and controls are shapes you just need to merge them all together into one shape and then you can just use the colour selector to change them all at the same time.