# How do I globally choose a fill color/gradient for my shapes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

The question suggested me this answer:
[How to select a global fill color for shapes](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/91185/how-to-select-a-global-fill-color-for-shapes)

However I want to achieve this using CS6, and I remember that time ago I have opened a sample .PSD file with a color switcher, it allowed me to select a fill color for all the underlying shapes (fill) color.

Comment: Photoshop has no global color option. What you linked to refers to **Illustrator's** global color options.  I don't really understand what you are asking.

Comment: There are many questions here regarding changing colors for multiple layers in Photoshop: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/photoshop-adjustment-layer-to-change-colors-of-multiple-layers , https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18441/how-do-i-change-all-instances-of-a-color-to-another-in-photoshop , https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60371/change-pixels-of-a-specific-color-to-another-color-across-all-layers

Comment: @Scott not layers in general but specifically the fill color of shapes.

Comment: There's no option for that.. and shapes kind of *are* layers in Photoshop. The questioned linked above are about the only solutions I am aware of.

Comment: @Scott I guess that https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/photoshop-adjustment-layer-to-change-colors-of-multiple-layers is the most similar answer to what I recall then.